# How to limit query runtime in SQL Anywhere 16

Tags: tomcat, sqlanywhere

For the last week I've had the joy of tracking down a query that was hogging all the database resources. I would like a way to proactively prevent such issues again. Is there a way to automatically prevent a query from taking more than 2 minutes to run (say) and killing it on the server if it is too slow?

There are ways to disconnect when the query is slow, but they still leave the query running on the server. I believe a resource governor would be what I need, but I have not found runtime or memory limits, just cursors and statements.

We are running SQL Anywhere 16 and connecting via the Tomcat connection pool with sajdbc4.jar.

Comment: Did you try [`Statement.setQueryTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-)

Comment: I had the same problem. The mitigation procedure was to limit the number of CPU a task could take using `SET OPTION PUBLIC.MAX_QUERY_TASKS=nnn`

Comment: @pascal, thank you for that information which I may use elsewhere, however I want to kill the query and not leave it slowly running in the database. If it takes too long my users are just going to give up on it anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am looking for a more global solution rather than setting for each query. However I think you are correct that it needs to be done client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, query timeouts must be set by the client and cannot be enforced on the database. Fortunately, the Tomcat 7 JDBC connection pool offers a [QueryTimeoutInterceptor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.QueryTimeoutInterceptor), which I have now implemented. It required one additional line in server.xml, within the connection pool definition:

`jdbcInterceptors="QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=90);SlowQueryReport(threshhold=60000)"`

The key part here is the `QueryTimeoutInterceptor`. The `SlowQueryReport` is there to warn me if we have queries that are starting to run long. There is also a simple way to expose these as JMX beans, which I am not doing.